# Easy way to give the time its own face in modeline?

Tags: mode-line

Is there an easy way to give the time (as displayed by `M-x display-time-mode`) a separate face in the modeline?

I don't need anything too fancy like powerline, I'd just like to be able to have the time in its own colour.

Cheers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Display Time Mode constructs a dynamic mode line based on `display-time-string-forms`, which is a customizable option.  The value of this option is a list of Emacs Lisp expressions.  Display Time Mode constructs a `(:eval …)` [mode line data](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Mode-Line-Data.html#Mode-Line-Data) from these expressions.

You can do whatever you want with these expressions, as long as they return strings.  Specifically, you can use the built-in `propertize` function to change the face of the string. For instance, the following construct will show the current time in 24hr format in `bold` face:

```
(setq display-time-string-forms
      '((propertize (format-time-string "%H:%M" now) 'face 'bold)))
```

Of course you can use whatever face you like instead.  Take a look at the default value of this variable in `time.el` to get an idea of what is possible.  You can visit the definition with `M-x find-variable RET display-time-string-forms`.

Note that if you customize `display-time-string-forms` this way, several other customization options of Display Time Mode (e.g. `display-time-format`, `display-time-24hr-format`, etc.) and mail display cease to work.  It doesn't matter since you are defining your very own display style, but you should be aware of.

---

PS: While writing this answer I realized that `time.el` is a bloody piece of  implementation-wise.  Notably, it defines a dozen of unprefixed dynamic variables with names as innocent as `now`.  If you enable Display Time Mode, you'd better make sure that you don't use any package which binds `now` as a closure variable.

In other words, be prepared for strange issues with other packages if you enable Display Time Mode.